# Solving Quadratic Newton polynomial not yielding same solution as divided differences

Tags: interpolation

So a Newton polynomial is defined by

> $$N(x) = a + b(x-x_0) + c(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$$

Solving this for $x \in \{x_0, x_1, x_2\}$ yields three equations, giving expressions for $a, b, c$:

1:
\begin{align*}
N(x_0) &= a + b(x_0-x_0) + c(x_0-x_0)(x_0-x_1)
\\&= a
\end{align*}

2:
\begin{align*}
N(x_1) &= a + b(x_1-x_0) + c(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_1)
\\&= N(x_0) + b(x_1-x_0)
\\\implies b &= \frac{N(x_1)-N(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}
\end{align*}

3:
\begin{align*}
N(x_2) &= a + b(x_2-x_0) + c(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)
\\ &= N(x_0) + \frac{N(x_1)-N(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}(x_2-x_0) + c(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)
\\\implies c &= \frac{\frac{N(x_2)-N(x_0)}{x_2-x_0}-\frac{N(x_1)-N(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}}{x_2-x_1}
\end{align*}

So another expression for $N(x)$ would be:

> $$
> N(x) = N(x_0) + \frac{N(x_1)-N(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}(x-x_0) + \frac{\frac{N(x_2)-N(x_0)}{x_2-x_0}-\frac{N(x_1)-N(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_0)(x-x_1)
> $$

However, according to the divided difference method, $c$ should instead be:
$$
\frac{\frac{N(x_2)-N(x_\color{red}1)}{x_2-x_\color{red}1}-\frac{N(x_1)-N(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}}{x_2-x_\color{red}0}
$$

Is there a mistake in my solution, or does the divided differences yield another solution?